# How to retrive data from restAPI in component in angular 4?

Tags: angular, components

I want to access restAPI parameters in my Component in angular 4. but I don't know how to do it. 
At my Component code for rest API is as follows, here I get complete data in result

```
this.apiSerivce
    .userlist({'offset':'0','limit':'10'})
    .subscribe( resultObj => this.userlist = resultObj)
```

and at my service code for user list is

```
userlist(data): Observable<userlist> {
    const headers = new Headers({ 
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
    });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this.http
               .post(this._url+'/Admin/User/UserList',data,options)
               .map((response: Response) => {

                   return <userlist>response.json();
                })
                .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

so I get result in my component.ts file on console.log

```
{
    "status": false,
    "message" : "User List"
    "response": [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    "total_rows" :8
}
```

I want to access status and message on my component. So how I am able to do this like in angular.js I am simply use

```
$scope.status = response.data.status
```

but I don't know how to do it in angular 4

Comment: If that json object is the value of `console.log(response);` then you can simply access the objects values with `response.status` or  `response.message` or `response['status']` should work as well.

Comment: I getting in component  this.userlist = resultObj, If I use this.userlist.message  or resultObj.message it shows error, I already defined both obj type of variable

Comment: Where do you get that error? In html? Where do you log that "so I get result in my component.ts file on console.log", in your component, right? So the data is delivered by your backend?

Comment: what's the error you get?

And what's the type of `this.userlist`?

Comment: It give Property 'response' does not exist on type 'userlist' and If define an interface for it , no option for defining array type there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the data in JSON easily. The code is based on the JSON display in your question:

```
this.apiSerivce.userlist({'offset':'0','limit':'10'})
    .subscribe( resultObj => ｛
    console.log(resultObj)
    this.userlist = resultObj.response
    //or
    //this.userlist = resultObj['response']
    this.status = resultObj.status
｝)
```

You can also define an interface for your turn type which will make the IDE recognise the property like [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/blob/master/samples/client/petstore/typescript-angular-v4/npm/model/apiResponse.ts).

Comment: It give Property 'response' does not exist on type 'userlist' and If define an interface for it , no option for defining array type there

Comment: please add console.log(resultObj) and see the output in developer tool of the browser.

Comment: cheer, glad to hear that!